# How can I plot the performance of my model over the test data set?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I want to plot 5 metrics (Loss, accuracy, recall, precision, F1-Score and mAP) of my model during the evaluation process over the test dataset. Is there a way I can do that?

Although I know there are no epochs in the `model.evaluate()` process, I tried to use `keras.callbacks.History()` to get the values I needed but it obviously failed.
My professor insists there's a way to do it but I haven't found it anywhere and I'm not sure. Maybe he's talking about something with `model.predict()`.

Comment: You are confusing training (learning parameters) with evaluating (computing metrics by the already learned parameters). So as you said NO EPOCHS in model.evaluate() because there is no learning and thus no curves by time to plot like loss or accuracy. While in evaluate you compute these metrics on a dataset without in a single time point (since you have only learned model status).

Comment: I think you are talking about the validation :), so sure this is can be done during training and then you will have two version from each metric in each epoch, one for the training data and one for the validation data e.g. loss and val_loss, accuracy and val_accuracy ...
These you can find them in the history of the model.fit() method, but make sure to pass the parameter validation_split

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to plot the metrics for every epochs in `model.evaluate()` as there is no epochs attribute for [model.evaluate()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#evaluate)

To compute above given metrics  you need to mention these metrics in `model.compile()` as below:

```
METRICS = [tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
          tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),
          tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=1)]
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy',METRICS])
```

then train the model to get each metric values at each epoch.

```
history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10, validation_data=validation_dataset)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/10
63/63 [==============================] - 10s 77ms/step - loss: 0.6081 - accuracy: 0.6160 - precision: 0.8187 - recall: 0.2980 - f1_score: 0.6667 - val_loss: 0.4201 - val_accuracy: 0.7327 - val_precision: 0.9315 - val_recall: 0.5037 - val_f1_score: 0.6678
Epoch 2/10
63/63 [==============================] - 4s 60ms/step - loss: 0.4464 - accuracy: 0.7550 - precision: 0.8706 - recall: 0.5990 - f1_score: 0.6667 - val_loss: 0.3182 - val_accuracy: 0.8304 - val_precision: 0.9589 - val_recall: 0.6914 - val_f1_score: 0.6678
```

Likewise, you can get these metric values for test data using `model.evaluate()`:

```
loss, accuracy, precision, recall, f1_score = model.evaluate(validation_dataset) # enter testing data
```

Output:

```
26/26 [==============================] - 2s 56ms/step - loss: 0.1194 - accuracy: 0.9530 - precision: 0.9737 - recall: 0.9296 - f1_score: 0.6600
```